# Pytest Collect Setup/Teardown

Tags: installation, pytest

Is there any way to collect Setup/Teardown ? If case setup/teardown error , i can restitute it? For example , I test an app.

```
collection = list()

SESSION:
  setup -> sucess # record it in to my collection  collection.append(session.setup)
case 1:
   setup -> sucess # record it in to my collection collection.append(case1.setup)
   test -> sucess
   teardown-> sucess # remove from my collection   collection.remove(case1.setup)
case 2:
   setup -> fail # traversing collections and run all setup again
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue can be solved by using a fixture with the correct scope and a yield.
You can change the functions/fixture according to what you want them to do of course.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def my_session_setup():
    my_setup_init()

@pytest.fixture()
def my_function_setup():
    my_setup_init()
    yield
    my_setup_clean_up()

def test_first(my_session_setup, my_function_setup):
    pass

def test_second(my_function_setup):
    pass
```